# How to solve this limit 0/0 indetermination?

Tags: limits

How can I solve this 0/0 indetermination, where the limit has t going towards 0?

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t^2}{\sin^2 t}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the fact that

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac t {\sin{t}} = 1$$

This is easily proven either by L'Hospital's rule, or Taylor series (or by geometry).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}$.  We know that

$$\lim_{t\to 0}f(t)=1$$

Your problem is $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{f(t)^2}$$